# Iterate thru all $_POST with almost identical ID

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a table whose number of rows are dynamic and each `<td>` id and name is different per row (i.e `<tr><td id="name_1" name="name_1"></td></tr> <tr><td id="name_2" name="name_2"></td></tr>`) which is passed to the controller thru `$_POST`

After getting the values of the table thru `$_POST` in the controller. I then want put each table row in array and then send it to model for insertion in the database.

Here is my code in my controller

```
public function submitPPMP(){
    print_r($_POST);
    $ppmp_id = $this->PPMP_model->submitPPMP();
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        $project_details = array(
            'project_id' => $ppmp_id,
            'supply_id' => $_POST['items_' . $counter],
            'quantity' => $_POST['qty_' + $counter],
            'price' => 1,
            'jan' => $_POST['jan_' . $counter],
            'feb' => $_POST['feb_' . $counter],
            'mar' => $_POST['mar_' . $counter],
            'apr' => $_POST['apr_' . $counter],
            'may' => $_POST['may_' . $counter],
            'jun' => $_POST['jun_' . $counter],
            'jul' => $_POST['jul_' . $counter],
            'aug' => $_POST['aug_' . $counter],
            'sep' => $_POST['sep_' . $counter],
            'oct' => $_POST['oct_' . $counter],
            'nov' => $_POST['nov_' . $counter],
            'dec' => $_POST['dec_' . $counter]
        );
        $counter = $counter + 1;
        //send the $project_details to model and insert to database
    }       
    print_r($project_details);
}
```

However, I can't seem to get the correct as I'm getting an `Undefined offset: 1` error at the line `'supply_id' => $_POST['items_' . $counter]`. What is the correct way of putting each row in an array and send it to the model?

My `$_POST` data is:-

```
 Array ( [unit] => [category_1] => 1 [items_1] => 5 [qty_1] => 1 [jan_1] => 1 [feb_1] => [mar_1] => [apr_1] => [may_1] => [jun_1] => [jul_1] => [aug_1] => [sep_1] => [oct_1] => [nov_1] => [dec_1] => [row_2] => 1 [items_2] => 27 [qty_2] => 1 [jan_2] => 1 [feb_2] => [mar_2] => [apr_2] => [may_2] => [jun_2] => [jul_2] => [aug_2] => [sep_2] => [oct_2] => [nov_2] => [dec_2] => [row_3] => 1 [items_3] => 20 [qty_3] => 1 [jan_3] => 1 [feb_3] => [mar_3] => [apr_3] => [may_3] => [jun_3] => [jul_3] => [aug_3] => [sep_3] => [oct_3] => [nov_3] => [dec_3] => [action] => )
```

Comment: Move `$counter = 1;` outside the loop, otherwise you aren't counting.

Comment: Thanks for that one however I'm still getting an offset error. It seems like even though it is iterating thru all the `$_POST` my `$counter` increments at every `$_POST` passed. How do I only increment every after the element with `dec_` name?

Comment: This is the post data `Array ( [unit] => [category_1] => 1 [items_1] => 5 [qty_1] => 1 [jan_1] => 1 [feb_1] => [mar_1] => [apr_1] => [may_1] => [jun_1] => [jul_1] => [aug_1] => [sep_1] => [oct_1] => [nov_1] => [dec_1] => [row_2] => 1 [items_2] => 27 [qty_2] => 1 [jan_2] => 1 [feb_2] => [mar_2] => [apr_2] => [may_2] => [jun_2] => [jul_2] => [aug_2] => [sep_2] => [oct_2] => [nov_2] => [dec_2] => [row_3] => 1 [items_3] => 20 [qty_3] => 1 [jan_3] => 1 [feb_3] => [mar_3] => [apr_3] => [may_3] => [jun_3] => [jul_3] => [aug_3] => [sep_3] => [oct_3] => [nov_3] => [dec_3] => [action] => )`

Comment: It is all correct. But when i put it in the array `$project_details` and use `print_r($project_details)` this is the output `Array ( [project_id] => 113 [supply_id] => [quantity] => [price] => 1 [jan] => [feb] => [mar] => [apr] => [may] => [jun] => [jul] => [aug] => [sep] => [oct] => [nov] => [dec] => )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest restructuring your data. It's currently a flat list like:

```
Array (
    [unit] =>
    [category_1] => 1
    [items_1] => 5
    [qty_1] => 1
    [jan_1] => 1
    ..
    [row_2] => 1
    [items_2] => 27
    [qty_2] => 1
    [jan_2] => 1
    ..
    [row_3] => 1
    [items_3] => 20
    [qty_3] => 1
    [jan_3] => 1
    ..
    [action] =>
)
```

If instead your data is like this:

```
array(
    "unit" => "",
    "category" => 1,
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "id" => 5,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "months" => array(
                "jan" => 1
                ..
            )
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 27,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "months" => array(
                "jan" => 1
                ..
            )
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 20,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "months" => array(
                "jan" => 1
                ..
            )
        )
    ),
    "action" => ""
)
```

Your logic is going to be much simpler. It's not very difficult to construct a request like this.

If the source of your request is an HTML form, you can do:

```
Quantity for item 1: <input type="text" name="items[0][quantity]" />
Quantity for item 2: <input type="text" name="items[1][quantity]" />
.. etc
```

If the source of the your request is a PHP script you can use [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query) to build a well formatted POST-body.

Comment: I'm using an HTML form where my table is located. A row can be added by a javascript. How can I make my `$_POST` data like that?

Comment: That's perfect. Have JavaScript generate the dynamic input names when it generates a new row, like: `quantity_element.name = "items[" + i + "][quantity]";`. I'm guessing right now you have something like `quantity_element.name = "qty_" + i;`. If you post your JavaScript code I can give a more tailored answer.

Comment: I am using `row.find('#items_' + oldId).attr('id', 'items_' + id).attr('name', 'items_' +id);` and this `$('#myTable').append(row);` to append the row to my table.

Comment: So should i make it `row.find('#items_' + oldId).attr('id', 'items_' + id).attr('name', 'items_[' + id + '][?]);`

Comment: I think `items_X` is the `id` of the item, right? So use: `.attr('name', 'items[' + id + '][id]');` This will give you: `array("items"=> array(array("id" => 123)));`

Comment: Yes. But I guess `$_POST` gets the elements with a `name="name"` so maybe I'll just try which ever works. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Is this what is it supposed to look like? `Array ( 
 [unit] => 
 [category_1] => 1 
 [items_1] => 5 
 [qty_1] => 1 
 [jan_1] => 1 
 [feb_1] => 
 [mar_1] => 
 [apr_1] => 
 [may_1] => 
 [jun_1] => 
 [jul_1] => 
 [aug_1] => 
 [sep_1] => 
 [oct_1] => 
 [nov_1] => 
 [dec_1] => 
 [category_] => Array ( 
  [2] => Array ( 
   [id] => 1 
  ) 
 ) 
 [items_] => Array ( 
  [2] => Array ( 
   [id] => 25 
  ) 
 ) 
 [qty_2] => 1 
 [jan_2] => 1 
 [feb_2] => 
 [mar_2] => 
 [apr_2] => 
 [may_2] => 
 [jun_2] => 
 [jul_2] => 
 [aug_2] => 
 [sep_2] => 
 [oct_2] => 
 [nov_2] => 
 [dec_2] => 
 [action] => 
)`

Comment: Something like that yea, now you also need to do all the other values (`qty`, `jan`, etc)

Comment: `Array ( [unit] => [category_1] => 1 [items_1] => 5 [qty_1] => 1 [jan_1] => 1 [feb_1] => [mar_1] => [apr_1] => [may_1] => [jun_1] => [jul_1] => [aug_1] => [sep_1] => [oct_1] => [nov_1] => [dec_1] => [category_] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) ) [items_] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [id] => 19 ) ) [qty_] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) ) [jan_] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) ) [feb_] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [id] => ) ) [mar_] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [id] => ) ) [apr_] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [id] => ) ) [may_] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [id] => ) ) [jun_] => Array ( [2] =>`

Comment: This is what happened but it doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: You're naming them `'jan_[' + i + '][id]'`, but that's not correct. The name should be `'items[' + i + '][jan]'`. `'items[' + i + '][quantity]'`, `'items[' + i + '][feb]'` etc.

Comment: Okay I did it. But there is a problem what should i put in the `name` of my hard coded table data? I'm sorry for being such a beginner. I've just started programming web 2 weeks ago.

Comment: How do I iterate thru each item? `$counter = 1;
  foreach ($_POST as $item){
   echo $item['items'][1];
   $counter++;
  }` Like this?

Comment: If you've got the datastructure that I posted you can do `foreach ($_POST["items"] as $item) { echo $item["id"]; }`

Comment: Yes. Thank you I've already got them. Thank you for giving me another way to make my array. This is new knowledge to me. It is indeed easier to work with my arrays when structured like this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to update the counter value on every loop, you should remove it from inside the foreach loop.

```
$counter = 1;
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
//...
```

Comment: Thanks for that one however I'm still getting an offset error. It seems like even though it is iterating thru all the `$_POST` my `$counter` increments at every `$_POST` passed. How do I only increment every after the element with `dec_` name?

Comment: If you change all `$_POST` inside the foreach with `$key`, will it work?

Comment: Actually the problem is with the logic you're implying there. Can you add to the question what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to put each all table datas in each row from the table to an array then send it to the model. Please check the edited version of my question. There is an example of my `$_POST` data.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a infinite loop you have a created,

everytime foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) loop is triggered your counter is again set to 1.

take the counter variable outside the for loop and you can put a while or a for loop condition.